# Extjs D3 Horizontal tree

Tags: d3.js, extjs, extjs6-modern

How to make the links start from the edge of the rectangle. [image]

I am using Extjs modern framework 6.2.1. I am using sencha architect premium controls. I have overridden the control to bring this custom view. Now i am facing problem on links. I dont know how to make start it from the edge of the rectangle. Any help will be greatly appreciated

Comment: I have found answer on this. Thanks

Comment: if you have found an answer could you perhaps post it here? I would be interested in the solution.  You can answer your own questions :) Thank you

Comment: var rectSize=246;
    this.setDiagonal(d3.svg.diagonal()
                                .source(function(d) { return {"x":d.source.x, "y":(d.source.y+rectSize)}; })
                             .target(function(d) { return {"x":(d.target.x), "y":d.target.y}; })
                                .projection(function(d) { return [d.y, d.x]; }));

Set the new diagonal with the new node y value. add the width of the node to source node y attr (Set it at the source). It will reflect for all the nodes.

Comment: Thanks! Btw you can post it as answer, not only comment ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`var rectSize=246; 
this.setDiagonal(d3.svg.diagonal()
.source(function(d) { return {"x":d.source.x, "y":(d.source.y+rectSize)}; }) 
.target(function(d) { return {"x":(d.target.x), "y":d.target.y}; })                                .projection(function(d) { return [d.y, d.x]; }));`

Set the new diagonal with the new node y value. add the width of the node to source node y attr (Set it at the source). It will reflect for all the nodes